# Oracle 11g Database and SAP Lumira connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sap-lumira

I'm trying to setup a connection between SAP Lumira Discovery and an Oracle database. I only know the SID of the database. When I try to connect I get the error :

> ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested
> in connect descriptor

So I assume the application is trying to connect using the service_name. Does anyone know how to use the SID?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like listener service is not running or your SID is wrong. Can you show how you make the connection?

Comment: The SID is correct. If i'm using the SID in other applications it works perfectly fine. It just seems that Lumira wants to use the service_name instead of the SID.

Comment: Have you used the service name then?

Comment: I found out the setvice_name. And it's working now. Thanks